# Multiple n:m clauses

Tags: sql, group-by, having-clause

I am trying to find products that have certain specs. Because of the complex combinations of specs I have another table that is a n:m relation to another table.

```
product
id | other data ...
---+---------------
1  | bike
2  | bus
3  | car

product_spec
product_id | spec_id
-----------+---------------
1          | 1
1          | 2
1          | 3
2          | 1
2          | 3
2          | 4
3          | 2
3          | 4
```

Now I need to find a product that has certain specs. This works nicely if I have a list of specs which the product **all** has to have:

```
SELECT p.id FROM product p, product_spec s
WHERE p.id = s.product_id AND s.spec_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY p.id HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 3
```

(with 3 being the number of specs that the product has to have) gives product 1

```
SELECT p.id FROM product p, product_spec s
WHERE p.id = s.product_id AND s.spec_id IN (1, 3)
GROUP BY p.id HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 2
```

gives product 1 and 2. So far so good. Now comes the trouble:

What if I want to get all products that have spec 1 **and** have **either** spec 2 or 4.

```
SELECT p.id FROM product p, product_spec s
WHERE p.id = s.product_id AND
    (s.spec_id = 1 OR s.spec_id IN (2, 4))
GROUP BY p.id HAVING COUNT(p.id) = 2
```

(clearly) returns product 1 and 3, but 3 erroneously because it does have both spec 2 and 4 but not 1.

I was thinking of giving the different spec clauses values (like spec group 1 = 1, spec group 2 = 2 (spec group 3 = 4, etc)), add them up and use `HAVING SUM(extra_field) = 3` but I have been unsuccessful in doing so.

**So, how would one do such a query?** Do I have to resort to multiple queries (and if, what would be the best approach)?

I am working with MySQL but I assume the question is not restricted to a single system.

Here are the statements to re-create these test tables:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO product (id, title) VALUES (1, 'bike'), (2, 'bus'), (3, 'car');
CREATE TABLE product_spec (
  product_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  spec_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id,spec_id)
);
INSERT INTO product_spec (product_id, spec_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 4);
```

Comment: +1 for adding the script for the test data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUM+CASE to compute the sums for the individual "categories" and use a combined HAVING query:

```
SELECT p.id 
FROM 
  product p, 
  product_spec s
WHERE p.id = s.product_id 
GROUP BY p.id 
HAVING 
  SUM(case when s.spec_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and 
  SUM(case when s.spec_id in (2,4) then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: Awesome. That's along my thought but I wasn't able to put it into SQL. Thanks!